# Summing value of nested dictionary list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary called 'topic_emb[topic][word]' I need to sumup the embeddings dimensions to single value for each word, for example:

```
{0:{'sky':  [0.229, 0.113, 0.445]}}
```

and I want as below:

```
{0:{'sky': 0.787}}
```

note: 0.229+ 0.113 + 0.445

Thank you for your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below code sample will work for your use case -

```
nested_dict= {0:{'sky':  [0.229, 0.113, 0.445]}}
for key,value in nested_dict.items():
    for key2,value2 in value.items():
        nested_dict[key][key2]=sum(value2)
print(nested_dict)
```

- As there is two folded nesting so I have used two for loops in
  nesting. If your nesting goes deep then you might have to increase
  the for loop in the nesting.

Answer (score 1):

This program would loop through all elements inside that dictionary:

```py
a = {0: {'sky':  [0.229, 0.113, 0.445]}, 1: {'sky1':  [0.229, 0.114, 0.445]}}
b = {}
for i in a:
    for k in a[i]:
        b[i] = {k: sum(a[i][k])}

print(b)
```

Output

`{0: {'sky': 0.787}, 1: {'sky1': 0.788}}`

Comment: @iforcebd Is the above solution working as you wanted?